# Issue with colors in Windows 10 using full dynamic range

Tags: windows, windows-10, colors, nvidia-geforce, windows-10-v20h2

After changing the `dynamic range` in **Nvidia Control Panel** to `full` I can't see the difference in colors. Previously I could see the difference as soon as I change that setting, but now nothing changes.
That happened around window's `20H2` update (unfortunately, I figured it out later, so I don't have a backup of previous Windows system atm) and I can't figure out another reason, that it's a Windows issue.

I've located a problem completely by accident, by browsing through internet. I've noticed, that image in windows image viewer and in browser had different colors, though previously there were no differencies. In Firefox, changing `gfx.color_management.mode` setting to `1` (instead of `0`) fixed the issue for me. For chrome it's `Force color profile`, set to `sRGB` or `scRGB linear`. Also, unexpectedly, enabling HDR in windows settings makes the image in Chrome look like in Firefox (with changes above).

Even though colors in browsers are OK, I'm not sure if this behaviour (I mean, that nothing changes for desktop image for example when I change dynamic range) is right, and I'm also not sure it's working in ALL my apps as I'd like to.

Here's an example of image in Firefox (1) and chrome before fix (2) in case it can be useful.

Firefox (and windows image viewer):

[image]

Google Chrome before fix:

[image]

**[Here's](https://static.zerochan.net/Mona.%28Genshin.Impact%29.full.3167243.jpg)** link to a full tested image.

What I tried:

- Re-enabling/disabling full dynamic range and output color depth (8/10);
- Using outdated Nvidia drivers;
- Updating all drivers on my PC;
- Setting color scheme in windows to CIE RGB;
- Using outdated browser versions;

My system configuration:

- Windows 10 Pro 20H2 build 19042.685;
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080ti with 460.89 driver version;
- Benq EW3270U monitor;

Comment: Your "full tested image" is an 8-bit untagged jpg. That doesn't qualify as a test image, because everything is at liberty to interpret as it likes.

Comment: @Tetsujin: It's 8x3=24 bit, which is normal for most jpg.

Comment: @harrymc - it has no profile, so there's no way to tell what it's **meant** to look like. You can assume sRGB, but it's merely an assumption. For what it's worth, it looks the same for me in the posted 'reference' image in a browser, in Photoshop & the first Firefox image… setting them to assume sRGB for untagged images. If you need to properly test an interpretation, you've got to start with a recognisable embedded profile, preferably for a 'consumer' uncalibrated machine, sRGB.